My Right Click will only "Extrude and Move on Normals"
I've seen on tutorials that use LoopTools that you have to right click to access some menu, but, when I try to right click while selecting a face, it only extrudes the face and doesn't access the menu displayed on the image.

I'm not really looking to extrude the face but to access the menu in the image.
I'm a beginner, on version 4.1

Hit Alt-E and see if the extrude menu pops up.

I figured it out. I just had to load the factory settings. Now it shows the Call Menu. (thats what I was looking for) Thanks.
